# migrate timer job from sharepoint 2007 to 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, solution-package, custom-timer-job

is it possible to migrate a custom timer job from SharePoint 2007 to 2010? is so,please let me know what points should i keep in mind before & after proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the following during the move:

1. You may only need WSP which contains timer job logic that can be deployed to 2010 platform.
2. You have to perform IISReset and restart timer job service to have full impact in 2010 version.
3. If you want to improve the timer job for 2010 (for whatever reasons) source code must be kept alive and you should be able to build/deploy updated WSPs.